# Wrong timezone in some devices - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, datetime

I have a react-native app running on various devices. Wherever I use time or datetime from `new Date()` or `moment` or by any other library, some devices show wrong time in the app. The actual device time is correct with respect to timezone but it shows a different time inside the app with a different timezone even if the timezone settings in the device is correctly set (Tried with Automatic and Manually set timezone).

I came across similar issues on stackoverflow and react-native's git issues stating that it can be fixed by updating **jsc-android** package manually. I already have the latest version of **jsc-android** in the app, but then too facing the same problem. This occurs even on latest version of `react-native: 0.61` too.

One of those devices are Redmi Note 5 (Android version 8.1.0).

Here is a screenshot of a sample app(Please ignore the orange stripes) showing incorrect timezone. The actual timezone is IST(Indian Standard Time)

[image: Screenshot]

You can compare the system time in the **Status Bar(11:21 AM)** and the **App time (3:51 AM).**

Here is the code for the above output (App.js)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      StatusBar,
    } from 'react-native';
    import moment from 'moment';
    
    const App = () => {  
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
          <Text>Time: {moment(new Date()).format("h:mm A")}</Text>
          <Text>Time String: {new Date().toTimeString()}</Text>
          <Text>Time Offset: {new Date().getTimezoneOffset()}</Text>
          <Text>Static Time (5:21 PM): {moment(new Date("2019-09-23T11:51:29.184Z")).format("h:mm A")}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Any Suggestions???

Comment: Does this happen *after* you change the system time zone? What if you restart your app, or if you restart the whole device?  In other words, is it possibly related to your app (or its environment) caching the time zone it was first loaded with?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, No, I just checked the system timezone and let it remain to it's default. I didn't change the timezone initially. Since it did not work as expected, I tried setting the timezone manually to IST, but then too it is showing the wrong time.

Comment: That's pretty strange then. Maybe you could show us the exact code that creates this sample app?  Is it really just is `new Date().toString()`?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I have updated the question with code.

Comment: Please also include `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Comment: And also check `getTimeZone` from [reactive-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize#gettimezone).

Comment: Also - is this running in a simulator? Or on the actual device?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, it's on actual device Redmi Note 5.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any answers for you.  It sounds like somehow, the device time zone is different than the app time zone.  My guess is if you compare time zones from Intl with reactive-native-localize (mentioned earlier), they will differ.  Maybe somewhere in your app you have a hardcoded time zone setting?  Good luck.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I have not hardcoded the timezone anywhere in the app. I'll see if I can find any other details.

Comment: Have you fixed this? When running `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`, I get UTC (should be the -3 for SaoPaulo). Wtf, I can't find anywhere an answer to this. My android (Redmi Note 8) have a right time.

Comment: @HenriqueBruno, Actually I was not able to find a solution for it at that time. But now I am able to think of a workaround. You can look up for a package which provides System Time settings and details. Or you can simply write a bridge and access the timezone and set it manually in javascript.

Comment: @Joshua, do you use the jscFlavor Intl workaround? I was using it, and it seems that it was removing the timezone even from the Date and not just Intl. I am now using the formatJs Intl polyfills (as it is much less heavier) and RNLocalize to get the timezone. I am now basically using this solution (ignore the first if()/hermes stuff): https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/23#issuecomment-675098624

Comment: No @HenriqueBruno, I didn't use the jscFlavor Intl. I ll too will try that solution.

Answer (score -6):

Everytime that I need to get the correct date from some location, I use this API : ***http://worldtimeapi.org/timezone/America/Sao_Paulo***.

Maybe it can helps you!

Comment: Actually I have got date and time from `new Date()` and `moment` throughout the app. So if I need to update the code to this API, then it will become a big work since date and time has been used in a lot of places. Is there any other way to find how this is occurring in some devices or a place to change the timezone of javascript's `new Date()`?